# Gathering scattered information and files into one page

Tags: http, iis, sharepoint, file-uri

We have different people joined to different projects. Many of those can be concurrently joined to more than one projects. In each project can be assigned some information in different ways. Could be in a form of network shared excel files or word files or a link to a CRM application or pdf etc. There is a scattered infromation in each project placed on our local network. So the employees complain that every time they are going to work on a project, they have to collect information from different places and applications.

So I thought of making an html page for each project that lists all the information related to it in the form of links. If it is a web application (intranet or internet) things are easy. But if it's a network file then I've found that browsers can't run and open files shared over the network as if they were being opened from file explorer. I have searched a lot but it seems that for security reasons this cannot be done. For example cannot open a network shared file with

```
"href=file://localnetworkserver/folder/shareredfile"
```

when the page is opened with http protocoll. I also thought the use of the SharePoint but this is a huge step for us. Because the concept has to do only with our internal local domain can this be resolved in some way to bypass those security restrictions?
I read somewhere that the http headers can be used so that the browser knows to dynamically open an application for each file, but this assumes that the files are stored on the web server and not on the network as shared files and thus cannot be edited.

Otherwise we have to collect and maintenance those scattered information making a web based app. A difficult way. Or making a desktop app that is not in our desires.

Comment: You can try to create a project, then publish these files to iis, and then give each user enough permissions to access these files.

Comment: To access these files from where? As I have already mentioned when access a file from web server (like iis) then you have a copy not the original file. The file is downloaded! I have resolved my problem and I will come back to post the solutions. There are 2 solutions!

Answer (score 1):

First solution

Using user.js to make a new firefox profile

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1264779

https://blog.scottlowe.org/2020/04/04/making-file-urls-work-again-in-firefox/

Second solution

I can make a free Outlook account and move the files on the onedrive. The free account gives you 5GB on onedrive and the ability to use Office applications for free! So I can have links to files that I can use them in my aggregator web page! Not a pro solution but it can work if needed and you haven't licensees for Ms Office to use the first solution